# Salesman Wise ODBC tally collection

Tags: odbc, tally, tdl

I want help in creating the collection in TDL. I need to retrieve the data salesman name wise for the voucher created.

i have created one collection

[Collection: RTSAllVouchers]
Type: Voucher
IsODBCTable: Yes
Fetch : *, AllLedgerEntries.*, LedgerEntries.*

but i am unable to get the data with salesman name.

need help

Answer (score 0):

where you have stored the salesman name? if at voucher level then try fetching it.